# Rails 3.0.1 set default file on a file_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, file, field, send

I have two rails applications which are connected through an API. In the first rails app I have many users with avatar images. Now I want to send them through a file_field (in form_for) to the second rails app.

The problem is that I don't want manualy select the image-path for each user. Better would be if the image_path would be automaticaly inserted when the page is loaded. At the moment there is for each user a page where I select his avatar image and click on send.
The location of the images is on the first rails server. So this means that I want to send avatar images from one rails server to another with a file_field.

Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to set a default image when opening a record for editing you have to do the following

In your edit view:

```
<%= form_for(@photo, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
  <%= f.submit "Change" %>
<% end %>
```

In your controller:

```
@photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
```

When you form gets displayed it will automatically assign the image in the database to the file_field.

Although the form might show "No File Selected", When you update your form your original image will still be there.